# SQL Server Error 26 (Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) Only When Debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a simple asp .net web project I'm working on, and while normally everything is going fine, if I try to debug the site, I get "SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified".  I'm not sure if its a weird code issue or a weird SQL Server Issue, but here are the system specs anyway.

My dev machine is Windows 7 32-bit, and a Windows Server 2008 VM (on the same Windows 7 Machine) runs both IIS and SQL Server 2008 Express.
I haven't had any other problems with the connection string I'm using, and I'm using the simple SA account.

Anyhow, thanks for the help.

Comment: Check out <a href="http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx">SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified</a> and see if it has any help.

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did this article helped you? Because I am not getting that because I am new in Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this, which I asked and self-answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347365/why-did-my-visual-studio-10-stop-using-app-config-for-my-sql-connection-string/11421271#11421271/).

My problem was Visual Studio was using a default app.config and thus a default connection string, instead of the one in my app.config, because I had put my app.config in its own directory, and the link VS uses to find the app.config is in the .proj file, which VS also occasionally changes to a default file path (I'm not sure what makes it do it, but it keeps happening randomly once a month or so). So when this happens, I need to go remove the XML node it auto-inserts in the .proj file.

Your problem might be the same or related. I.e., probably in debug mode, it's using the wrong config file and/or connection string. I figured this out by debugging and seeing what connection string it was actually trying to use at run-time, and then searching the whole solution for that wrong connection string, and where THAT was, and what referenced THAT, etc.